# How to get URL segments with next/navigation in Next.js

Tags: next.js, url-routing, next.js13, next-router

I’m currently working on a Next.js project and I’m trying to use the
`useSearchParams` or `useParams` hook from the `next/navigation` to access URL segments. I have used [Rewrite parameters](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites#rewrite-parameters) to map `source: '/chat/:id'` to `destination: '/chat'` so it gets rewritten to the chat page with the `:id` segment. However, I’m encountering an issue where useParams is returning an empty object and useSearchParams returning null.

```
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

export default function MyComponent() {
  // Current URL -> '/chat/1' (/chat/:id)
  const params = useParams()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  console.log("params", params) // This logs an empty object {}
  console.log("searchParams", searchParams.get("id")) // This logs null
}
```

I understand that useParams only returns the [dynamic params](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) like `/chat/[id]` but when I navigate to a URL like `/chat/:id`, I expect `searchParams.get("id")` to return the value for `:id`, but it’s returning null. With `router.query` from `next/router` it gives the correct value. Is there no way to access the `:id` segment using `next/navigation`?

Is this the expected behaviour for `useSearchParams` and `useParams` when trying to access URL segments, or am I missing something?

P.S. `next/navigation` doesn't seem to export `beforePopstate` or other router events either.

Edit: Just realized the `usePathname()` returns the pathname with the `:id` segment which is different from the behaviour of the pathname value returned from `next/router` which only returns `/chat` and that is the actual pathname.

Answer (score 2):

The `useSearchParams` hook function is used to get the values ​​that are placed after your page pathname, such filters and other values.
For example, you can have `http://appname/chat/[id]` as your pathname, and you could search`http://appname/chat/1?value=2` at the browser.

Using `useSearchParams().get("value")` you'll get the value `2`, and using `useParams().id` you'll get the value `1`. You should use `useParams` to get the values ​​placed inside the pathname and use `useSeachParams` to get the values ​​that come after it.

Comment: I do not think you have tested it out. Because `useParams().id` returns `undefined` because useParams returns an empty object in this case since it does not have any dynamic routes. Docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params#returns) says useParams only works for dynamic route params such as `/blog/[slug]` where `useParams().slug` will return the value.

Comment: Great Solution! <3 Loved it